# Convert array into different structure using array values

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a simple way to get the latter array from the former?

Source array :

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Target structure:

```
[
    {id: 1, text: idToName(1)},
    {id: 2, text: idToName(2)},
    {id: 3, text: idToName(3)},
    {id: 4, text: idToName(4)},
    {id: 5, text: idToName(5)}
]
```

Comment: That's not a *JSON* array. Do you simply mean an array *in Javascript*?

Comment: I meant object array I guess if JSON array is incorrect to qualify it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's easy to use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) here:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var mapped = array.map(function(num) { return { id: num, text: idToName(num) }; });
```

With ES6 [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) it [would be](https://jsbin.com/hixufijixo/edit?js,console):

```
let mapped = array.map(num => ({ id: num, text: idToName(num) }));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var _x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(function(v){
    return {"id":v, "text":idToName(v)};
});
```

Use `.map`, [Live Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jzsk4wtn/)

Or in **ES6**

```
var _x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(v => ({"id":v, "text":idToName(v)}));
```

[Live Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jzsk4wtn/1/)